Stairs landing door placement
I bought my house in 2021. It was built in 2016. I have a stairway door going upstairs to my loft. The landing isn't large enough. My dog recently fell down the stairs and died from hitting the door. I want to correct this mistake from the original builder. How can I correct this mistake






Oh man, I'm sorry about your dog.  Can you give us photos of what this looks like below the stairs, i.e. what's on the other side?  Sounds like your best option is to reprofile the stairs (hopefully there's room in the rise/run to shorten the treads or raise the risers.  That, or install some kind of cushioning system at the bottom, or possibly some kind of net arrestor similar to what's used for aircraft.

Actually, it may also help to use carpet stair treads that wrap over the nose, instead of whatever you have on there now.  Our bare wood treads were slick and our little dog was afraid to go down them.  But we got the carpet covers and she has no problems now.  These are what we got, but there are many others: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PCPDVSZ

Is the door needed to do something like security, stop excess noise, stop little kids from going up?  If not, removing the door and using a curtain, might be an idea.

@crip659 The door is needed, the upstairs loft has its own HVAC. Also it keeps my 18 month old from trying to climb up the stairs

@Huesmann There is room at the bottom to bring the door out, but my wife is afraid it will look weird. I will send another photo of the entry way how the door looks now. We did add some textured pads to the stairs, and my dog walked up and down the stairs hundreds of times. But he was getting senior, and had history of seizures. So he may have just slipped.

Even moving the door away, those stairs are high enough that anyone slipping will build up enough momentum  to hit the door.

@crip659 I Also thought about getting a really cheap/crappy door. So that if someone fell, they would just bust right through it.

So I see a new pic of the area at the bottom of the stairs (with the doors), but I'd still like to see one of what is below the stairs.  Is there another staircase below?  Another room?  Basically, show us what kind of space is there.

Without the 18 month old, I might recommend a spring catch to keep it close.

@Huesmann I attached 2 more photos. There is a utility closet under the stairs. I thought I might be able to wrap around the stairs into the garage, but that would be a lot of work.

It looks like there's a door at the top. If so, you really don't need the door at the bottom to prevent air flow for HVAC purposes. Fitting a child gate would address the issue of the kid, and many of those are friction fit, or flimsy enough that an adult would fall straight through them. I feel compelled to point out that while I understand your concern, this was an exceptionally unusual event and you may be overprotecting.

@keshlam The current setup is not code compliant. You need at least 36 inches at the bottom for a landing. The code exists for a reason, and my dog is proof of that. I wouldn't be able to forgive myself if my wife or child fell down and struck the door in a similar fashion. The upstairs does not have a door, it is open space.

@27560 I think what keshlam is saying is that you have a door at the top, and no door at the bottom.  The floor at the bottom is the landing.  If you put the baby gate at the bottom, the kid can't fall down the stairs.  You may need a tall gate to make it easier for adults to unlatch it (bending down from the high stairs).  Barring that, you have to move your water heater forward and shift the stairs accordingly.

@Huesmann: Exactly. Some gates, I believe, have a release for their latch that extends or can be extended upward, which might be easier to operate in this case.

@Huesmann The door you see at the top is a 3 ft tall door that is to access the HVAC system. There isn't an upstairs door

So how hard would it be to add one?

@Huesmann The walls on the left and right side of the stairs are only half height. They don't go all the way up to the ceiling. Adding a door would require quite a bit of framing

@Huesmann I added a photo of the top of the stairs for reference

@27560 well, do you want to do your framing when you have to reframe to shift the stairs themselves, or just the walls at the top?
